# parse feed url error

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I'm parseing the rss feed and displaying it but it is showing only one record.I'm using the following javascript . Please let me know how can I show all records in one div?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.get("http://www.footballfriendsonline.com/blogs/rss.xml", function (data) {
  $(data).find('item').each(function(i){
   var title = $(this).find('title').text();
    var container=$(this).find('description').text();
     var img_url = $('img',container).attr('src');
     var url=$(this).find('link').text();

   var result='<li><a href="'+url+'" target="_blank"><span>'+title+'</span><span><img src="'+img_url+'" width="154" height="115"></span></li>';
 $("#new_widget").html(result);
  });
   });
  });
   </script>
   <div id="new_widget"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be overwriting your html by calling this inside the $.each loop... You need to call this outside the loop..

```
$("#new_widget").html(result);
```

Try this piece of code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("http://www.footballfriendsonline.com/blogs/rss.xml", function(data) {
        var result = '';
        $(data).find('item').each(function(i) {
            var title = $(this).find('title').text();
            var container = $(this).find('description').text();
            var img_url = $('img', container).attr('src');
            var url = $(this).find('link').text();

            result += '<li><a href="' + url + '" target="_blank"><span>' + title + '</span><span><img src="' + img_url + '" width="154" height="115"></span></li>';

        });
        $("#new_widget").html(result);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

use `append` instead of `html`

`html` clear the previous html of div that's why you will get last feed

like this

```
$("#new_widget").append(result);
```

instead of

```
$("#new_widget").html(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your script. First, each loop result is overwriting the previous one. Second you are attaching li elements to a div, while you should attach them to an ol or ul element.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var result="";
$(document).ready(function () {
$.get("http://www.footballfriendsonline.com/blogs/rss.xml", function (data) {
$(data).find('item').each(function(i){
...
result+='<li><a href="'+url+'" target="_blank"><span>'+title+'</span><span><img src="'+img_url+'" width="154" height="115"></span></li>';
});
$("#new_widget").html(result);
});
});
</script>
<ul id="new_widget"></ul>
```